# How to optimize query when dynamically filtering by partition field

Tags: google-bigquery

I have 2 tables, one massive one with event level data for every session and the other one with campaign information for a specific day. Table one is partition by date (not clustered).

What I'm trying to do is to query from table 1 only dates where `promo` value in the table 2 is true but in the same time I don't want to scan all rows in the table 1 (because what's the point of partitioning).

I tried queries below but for both of them BQ processing the whole table (which I understand for the second one, but not really for the first one). Is there a more efficient way to perform that action (so BQ would scan only partitions that are provided by the output of `fltr` subquery? (so the same way if I passed `WHERE date = '2020-01-02' or date = '2020-01-03'`)

```
#query1
with events as (

select * from  table1

),
fltr as (

SELECT  distinct date FROM table2
where promo 

)

select * from events inner join fltr using( date)

#query2
with events as (

select * from  table1

),

fltr as (

SELECT  distinct date FROM table2
where promo 

)

select * from events 
where date in (select date from fltr)
```

Structures below:

table1

```
id|    date    | s_id | event 
--------------------------------
1 | 2020-01-01 | sid1 | action_x
2 | 2020-01-01 | sid1 | action_y
3 | 2020-01-01 | sid1 | action_z
4 | 2020-01-01 | sid1 | action_a
1 | 2020-01-02 | sid2 | action_x
2 | 2020-01-02 | sid2 | action_y
3 | 2020-01-02 | sid2 | action_z
4 | 2020-01-02 | sid2 | action_a
1 | 2020-01-03 | sid3 | action_x
2 | 2020-01-03 | sid3 | action_y
3 | 2020-01-03 | sid3 | action_z
4 | 2020-01-03 | sid3 | action_a
```

Table2

```
      date | promo
------------------
2020-01-01 | FALSE
2020-01-02 | TRUE
2020-01-03 | TRUE
2020-01-04 | FALSE
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To limit the partitions that are scanned in a query, you need to use a constant expression to filter the partition column.

In your case, in order to leverage partition, you need to obtain the dates from table-2 in advance and use them as constant values to filter table_1's date.
One option is to use BQ script.

```
DECLARE promo_dates ARRAY<DATE>;

SET promo_dates = (
  SELECT 
    ARRAY_AGG(
      DISTINCT date
    )
  FROM table2
  WHERE promo 
);

SELECT 
  *
FROM table1
WHERE date IN UNNEST(promo_dates)
```

See more details (your scenario is exactly the 2nd example in the doc section below)

https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/querying-partitioned-tables#pruning_limiting_partitions

Comment: How did I miss that... Works like a charm. Thank you Hui!